# Django cannot import name _imaging

Tags: django, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, wsgi, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to deploy a Django application, however, during deployment, I'm getting the following error:

```
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.256427 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179] mod_wsgi (pid=6870): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/websites/www-davixxa/src/davixxa_website/production.wsgi'.
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.256883 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.257362 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 58, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.257483 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 134, in get_response
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.257492 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]     from . import _imaging as core
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.257519 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.257624 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512] ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging'
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.257760 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512] 
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.257864 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 374, in resolve
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.257872 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.257896 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.257905 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512] 
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.258021 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.258113 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.258224 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.258537 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.258855 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.259248 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 177, in __call__
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.259357 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.259365 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.259390 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.259644 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 230, in get_response
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.259745 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.259756 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.259778 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.260018 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 292, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.260108 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.260118 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]     if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.260140 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.260285 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.260376 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.260463 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.260474 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.260567 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.260702 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.260793 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.260881 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.260889 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.260983 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.261126 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.261219 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.261284 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.261373 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/src/davixxa_website/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.261465 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.261473 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     url(r'^markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls')),
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.261570 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.261717 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.261811 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.261902 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.261910 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.262005 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.262135 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.262223 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.262310 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.262318 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.262464 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.262553 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/src/davixxa_website/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.262639 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.262648 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]     url(r'^markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls')),
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.262740 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.262872 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.262960 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.263047 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.263056 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.263148 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.263281 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.263367 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.263430 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.263521 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/markdownx/urls.py", line 9, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.263668 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     from .views import (
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.263659 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.263833 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.263927 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/markdownx/views.py", line 5, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.264018 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.264026 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     from .forms import ImageForm
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.264122 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.264258 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.264348 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/markdownx/forms.py", line 13, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.264436 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.264445 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     from .utils import scale_and_crop, xml_has_javascript
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.264537 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.264720 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/markdownx/utils.py", line 3, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.264805 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/markdownx/urls.py", line 9, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.264812 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     from PIL import Image
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.264834 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]     from .views import (
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.265016 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 58, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.265100 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/markdownx/views.py", line 5, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.265108 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     from . import _imaging as core
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.265132 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]     from .forms import ImageForm
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.265229 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179] ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging'
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.265350 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179] 
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.265445 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/markdownx/forms.py", line 13, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.265453 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.265477 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]     from .utils import scale_and_crop, xml_has_javascript
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.265518 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179] 
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.265640 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.265734 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/markdownx/utils.py", line 3, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.265819 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]     from PIL import Image
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.265910 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 177, in __call__
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.265976 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.266065 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 58, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.266125 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512]     from . import _imaging as core
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.266212 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 230, in get_response
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.266307 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523728705280] [remote 178.155.217.10:512] ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging'
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.266315 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.267815 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 292, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.267894 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.268181 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.268237 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.268500 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.268548 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.268701 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.268732 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.268828 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.268917 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.269004 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.269132 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.269224 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.269313 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.269403 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.269546 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/src/davixxa_website/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.269575 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     url(r'^markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls')),
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.269708 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.269737 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.269862 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.269889 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.269980 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.270067 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.270154 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.270241 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.270327 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.270413 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.270500 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.270637 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/markdownx/urls.py", line 9, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.270665 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     from .views import (
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.270794 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/markdownx/views.py", line 5, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.270822 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     from .forms import ImageForm
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.270950 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/markdownx/forms.py", line 13, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.271006 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     from .utils import scale_and_crop, xml_has_javascript
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.271147 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/markdownx/utils.py", line 3, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.271185 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     from PIL import Image
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.271345 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]   File "/home/websites/www-davixxa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 58, in <module>
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.271376 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179]     from . import _imaging as core
[Mon Feb 12 20:56:17.271479 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6870:tid 126523603367680] [remote 178.155.217.10:1179] ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: As elaborated on in the comments below, currently, it seems like mod_wsgi isn't compiled for 3.5, but 3.4 instead. I've also gone ahead and expanded my error.

Comment: Please paste errors directly into the question, rather than using an external site, where the link may break in future.

Comment: Verify what version of Python mod_wsgi is actually compiled for. It possibly isn't compiled for Python 3.5 as you think. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use

Comment: You seem to be right with regards to that. It seems to be compiled for 3.4, how would I go by updating it to one compiled for 3.5?

Comment: Uninstall the system mod_wsgi package, which is likely hopelessly out of date anyway and install mod_wsgi from source code yourself. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: Using the guide listed here: http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html -- I can't find the place where to paste in the `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` line. I'm running Debian Jessie, using Apache 2.4.